# Filter some Switch element from list of other elements from XML file

Tags: android, traversal

I am creating an android application in which i have a activity which contain several elements like Switch, TextView etc.

I need to get the values from all Switch elements whether it is checked or not.

it will be great if anyone show me the proper way to transfer multiple values to different activity for further calculation.

Thanks

here is my XML code:

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/configSwitchHldr"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp" >

                <TextView 
                    android:text="@string/coreHardware"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    />
                <View 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="2dp"       
                   android:background="#363636" />
                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="14.5sp"
                    android:textOn="ON"
                    android:textOff="OFF"
                    android:text="CPU"              
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    />
                <View 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="1dp"       
                   android:background="#363636" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="14.5sp"
                    android:textOn="ON"
                    android:textOff="OFF"
                    android:text="Memory" 
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                <View 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="1dp"       
                   android:background="#363636" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="14.5sp"
                    android:textOn="ON"
                    android:textOff="OFF"
                    android:text="Storage" 
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                <View 
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="1dp"       
                   android:background="#363636" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean about: "it will be great if anyone show me the proper way to transfer multiple values to different activity for further calculation."
Also how many widgets do you want to get values from? Sometimes it's more hassle to create some generic method for getting all values than just getting the values one at the time...

Comment: i will take input from user to one activity then transfer those values to another activity in same app for further processing.

i have multiple switch element in one activity. i want to get all the values of switch elements (is it true or false) send it to another activity for process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on your comment this is how it could be done:

In your first `Activity`, you would need a method, that gathers all the switches states and pass them along to the next activity. Passing parameters along to other Activities can be achieved by putting them inside the `Intent` you send to open the new `Activity`.

The method for getting the `Switches` states and passing them to a new `Activity` would roughly look something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("switch1", switch1.isChecked());
i.putExtra("switch2", switch2.isChecked());
i.putExtra("switch3", switch3.isChecked());
startActivity(i);
```

Put this inside the onClickListener for a `Button` for instance like so:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("switch1", switch1.isChecked());
        i.putExtra("switch2", switch2.isChecked());
        i.putExtra("switch3", switch3.isChecked());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Now when you click the `Button` you'll be sent to NewActivity.

To retrieve the parameters passed on from the MainActivity, you should do something like this in you onCreate method of the NewActivity:

```
boolean bool1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("switch1");
boolean bool2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("switch2");
boolean bool3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("switch3");
```

You could pass the variables on from MainActivity by putting them inside a boolean array, but that is overkill in my opinion.

Also take a look at this SO post: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) - there's a lot of these.